# Webpack: library var is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, undefined, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting an `undefined` error for the main library variable when trying to use my Webpack bundled library.

I tried many different solutions from StackOverflow, such as using `globalObject: 'this'` in my webpack.config, but none of the solutions from StackOverflow seem to be working.

The code is very simple and I don't see any reason why it would be throwing an error, but for some reason it is.

This is my webpack.config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');

function gen_html_example(filename, title){
   return new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: title,
      filename: "examples/" + filename,
      template: "./src/examples/" + filename,
      alwaysWriteToDisk: true
   })
}

module.exports = {
   entry: './src/index.js',
   mode: 'development',
   devtool: 'inline-source-map',
   output: {
      filename: 'main.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      libraryTarget: "var",
      library: "sdnd",
      clean: true,
   },
   devServer: {
       static: './dist/examples',
   },
   plugins: [
       new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
           title: 'Index',
           filename: "examples/index.html",
           template: "./src/examples/index.html",
           alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
       }),
       gen_html_example("1.html", "Example #1"),

       new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
   ],
 };
```

src/index.js:

```
export var test  = 0;
```

1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <style>
              .droppable{
                  background-color: lightgray;
                  width: 100%;
                  height: 50px;
                  cursor: move;
              }

              #dropzone{
                  width: 400px;
                  height: 400px;
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  padding: 5px;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
              }
          </style>
          <script defer src="../main.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>

           <div id="dropzone">

           </div>


           <script>
               const a = sdnd.test;
           </script>
       </body>
  </html>
```

I'm getting the following error on page 1.html when running with webpack-dev-server:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: sdnd is not defined at 1.html:34:23`

In the bundled `main.js` file there is a line `sdnd = __webpack_exports__;`, so I don't understand why it wouldn't be working

Answer (score 0):

### *Solved:*

The reason I was getting the error is because of `HtmlWebpackPlugin` - it was adding a `defer` attribute to the loaded script, which caused the inline script to be executed before the bundle had been loaded. I resolved this by adding `scriptLoading: "blocking"` and
`inject: "head"` properties to `HtmlWebpackPlugin` calls